# What are the best way to solve text overlapping?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I have a pie chart, this is the code

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

title = "Population of Singapore by age(2018)"
titlelen = len(title)
print("{:*^{titlelen}}".format(title, titlelen=titlelen+6))
print()
data = np.genfromtxt("ca1_data/population.csv",
               delimiter=',',skip_header=1,
               dtype=[('Year','i4'),('Race','U50'),('Age','U50'),('Population','i4')],
               missing_values=['na','-'],filling_values=[0])
age = data[(data['Year']==2018) & (data['Race']=='Total Citizen') & (data   ['Age']!='65 Years & Over') & (data['Age']!='70 Years & Over') & (data['Age']!='75 Years & Over') & (data['Age']!='80 Years & Over')]['Age']
population = data[(data['Year']==2018) & (data['Race']=='Total Citizen') & (data['Age']!='65 Years & Over') & (data['Age']!='70 Years & Over') & (data['Age']!='75 Years & Over') & (data['Age']!='80 Years & Over')]['Population'] 
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(20,10))
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)

ax1.pie(population, labels=age,autopct='%1.1f%%',
         startangle=90)

plt.title(title)
ax1.axis('equal')

plt.show()
```

The code does produce the correct output but some texts are overlapping, i tried increasing the figsize however it makes every texts small and some of them are above the title. Is there better way to solve this?
This is the value of age

```
['0  -  4 Years' '5  -  9 Years' '10 - 14 Years' '15 - 19 Years'
 '20 - 24 Years' '25 - 29 Years' '30 - 34 Years' '35 - 39 Years'
 '40 - 44 Years' '45 - 49 Years' '50 - 54 Years' '55 - 59 Years'
 '60 - 64 Years' '65 - 69 Years' '70 - 74 Years' '75 - 79 Years'
 '80 - 84 Years' '85 Years & Over']
```

This is the value of population

```
[172621 175796 180222 205723 237046 250958 217874 224625 227556 247329
 267845 280396 257548 202905 130055  89536  55232  48669]
```

Thanks in advance!

Update:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
​
title = "Population of Singapore by age(2018)"
titlelen = len(title)
print("{:*^{titlelen}}".format(title, titlelen=titlelen+6))
print()
data = np.genfromtxt("ca1_data/population.csv",
               delimiter=',',skip_header=1,
               dtype=[('Year','i4'),('Race','U50'),('Age','U50'),('Population','i4')],
               missing_values=['na','-'],filling_values=[0])
age = ['0  -  4 Years', '5  -  9 Years', '10 - 14 Years', '15 - 19 Years',
 '20 - 24 Years', '25 - 29 Years', '30 - 34 Years', '35 - 39 Years',
 '40 - 44 Years', '45 - 49 Years', '50 - 54 Years', '55 - 59 Years',
 '60 - 64 Years', '65 - 69 Years', '70 - 74 Years', '75 - 79 Years',
 '80 - 84 Years', '85 Years & Over']
population = [172621, 175796, 180222, 205723, 237046, 250958, 217874, 224625, 227556, 247329,
 267845,280396, 257548, 202905, 130055,  89536,  55232,  48669]
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(20,10))
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)
​
ax1.pie(population, labels=age,autopct='%1.1f%%',
         startangle=90)
​
plt.title(title)
ax1.axis('equal')
​
plt.show()
```

This should be the working code

Comment: Can you please provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your problem so we can actually help?

Comment: Hi, i have updated the code. Thanks for replying!

Comment: Reproducible means that we can actually run the code on our own computer. We do not have access to the csv file that you read, so we cannot try ourselves.